# Is my furnace vent installed correctly

Tags: vent

96% furnace. The air intake was not directed and terminated outside as the old furnace was.  The installer said that over the years it has been determined that the inside basement air is better for the furnace.  Outside air intake is now old school. The pipe was there from the old furnace.  I’m not sure why they didn’t reattach it( instead cut it off ).
Also there isn’t any name plate on the furnace.  Installer said that happens at the factory.  Many brands come off the same line.  I looked inside for serial a number / date tag and found nothing. Seems like there is always something around the burner box area. Outside the furnace on the side is a model number G96vtn1002130a enter image description here

[image]
[image: Vent pipe cut off]

Comment: Installer sounds iffy at best.  Even if other brands come off the same line they stick name plates and serial numbers on, they are needed so right replacement parts are used.  Would get another known good installation company to check.

Comment: " Outside air intake is now old school."  Not sure I agree with that.  Sounds like your installer just didn't want to be bothered.  I will defer to more experienced HVAC experts.

Comment: Would add to SteveSh comment, if living where it gets very cold the exhaust vent can freeze close, inside air may make it worst and think with today's tight houses outside air is required for fuel heating units.

Comment: You should definitely get another qualified installer to look it over. The problem is that you need air to enter the house to make up for the air going out. If your house is well sealed, this causes the entire house to be under negative pressure until something starts to leak. The outside air vent is a controlled leak that is not influenced by opening and closing doors and windows or randoms leaks in your building envelope. This is important for proper burner operation.

Comment: In my experience, high-efficiency furnaces are always direct-vented, including the intake. This is wrong. Pulling conditioned air for combustion reduces efficiency, for one thing. That air now comes in through leaks in your home and cools it.

Answer (score 2):

The other intake pipe appears to be capped. With no direct air inlet and the old line capped this sets up problems including code compliance issues.

I would verify with a local building code inspector, I don’t do furnaces full time but that would not pass inspection in my jurisdiction, to me it looks like a lazy installer trying to save a buck.

So my answer is NO it is not right. it should have a fresh air source.